# Creating matching variables in R

Tags: r, merge, survey

I have two datasets, one from the head of the household and from the other spouse. I would like to merge these two. However, I feel that I may be carrying out the merge incorrectly. I would use the table below to elaborate on my problem.

```
Area    Household    line 
1         11            7
11        1             7
```

To create the matching variable , I have to add these three variables and I expect the MV to come out as

```
1 11 7 
11 1 7
```

But what I get is 1117 for these two different individuals, when I use the code below.

```
MV <-as.numeric (paste0(x$area, x$household, x$line , sep=""))
```

How do I ensure that I get the expected MV?

Comment: Do you need `MV <- paste(x$area, x$household, x$line)`

Comment: Thanks , that is what I ended up using and it worked